# rails require local file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, require

I have rails project. And I want to add code to class MainParserPlugin ( path : app/controllers/admin/main_parser_plugin.rb") from class ParserPlagin (path :  "app/controllers/admin/parser_plugin.rb")

main_parser_plugin.rb:

```
 require 'parser_plugin'
 class Admin::MainParserPlugin < ApplicationController
    #Some code 
 end
```

But it appear an error :
     cannot load such file -- parser_plugin

Can you tell me what path I must put, to work it well?

Answer (score 3):

Within `config/application.rb` you'll need to add any subdirectories under `app/models` to the `autoload_path` by adding the following line:

`config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]`